# How to Fix Spacing Between Item Number and Caption in List of Figures

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, tocloft, horizontal-spacing

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\LARGE\textbf \hfill LIST OF ILLUSTRATIONS \hfill}


\newcommand\NewCaption[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{\scshape{#2 #1}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{%         % Figure label command
  \scshape                          % Small caps
  \bfseries                         % Bold
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}  % Dotted line
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageA Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-b}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageB Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: In the *List of Illustrations*  display, how may I shift the numbers 1 and 2 so that they lie 15pt to the left of the captions? I would like to keep the captions vertically aligned directly under the title---so I inquire as to how to shift the item numbers to the right.

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious: Your code loads the `tocloft` package, but you don't appear to be making any use of it. Also, the figures' captions don't display a number, yet the figure numbers show up in the LoF. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico Yes; it does seem odd. However, it seems (and I don't know why)  that if I remove it, I encounter a problem with the display. The only thing that I can surmise is that `\listofigures` is somehow related to the `tocloft` package.

Comment: The caption numbers are handled by `\numberline`, which uses `\@tempdima` for the spacing.  `\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo You wouldn't perhaps consider posting this as a working answer? I am confused as to what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve an almost identical effect just by changing the arguments of `\@dottedtocline`.  The main difference is that the numbers are normally left justified within the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Allows one to make bold smallcaps.

%\usepackage{tocloft}% redundant
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\LARGE\textbf LIST OF ILLUSTRATIONS}}


\newcommand\NewCaption[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{\scshape{#2 #1}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{%         % Figure label command
  \scshape                          % Small caps
  \bfseries                         % Bold
  \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil ##1\hskip 15pt}}% right justified
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}  % #1 = tocdepth check, #2 = left margin, #3 = \@tempdima
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-a}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageA Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth,angle=0]{example-image-b}
  \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} \vspace{10pt}
    \NewCaption{ImageB Caption}{\Large}
  \label{fig:Image Caption}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this post.